# storing file with Large Object Postgres with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, promise

I have a simple HTML form with a file input. I need to save the file with Postgres Large Object but I'm having issues with the fileStream.pipe. It should be in a Promise itself like so:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on('finish', resolve(oid));
    stream.on('error', reject);
});
```

But it wouldn't work since it would result into a Promise in a Promise. The complete functions are:

```
function storeLargeObject(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pgp.db.tx(tx => {
            const man = new LargeObjectManager({pgPromise: tx});
            return man.createAndWritableStreamAsync(bufferSize);

        }).then(([oid, stream]) => {
            const fileStream = createReadStream(path);
            fileStream.pipe(stream);

            stream.on('finish', resolve(oid));
            stream.on('error', reject);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        });
    });
}

const addBinary = (req, res) => {
    pgp.db.oneOrNone({
        text: insertQuery,
        values: values
    }).then(f => {
        let explFile = req.files.bin;
        let uploadPath = __dirname + '/' + f.id;

        if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
            res.status(400).send('No File was uploaded.');
            return;
        }
        explFile.mv(uploadPath, async function (err) {
            if (err)
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            let newOid = await storeLargeObject(uploadPath);
            fs.unlink(uploadPath, err => console.log(err));
            coupleIds(exp.id, newOid);
            return res.status(200).send({
                status: "success",
                message: "File successfully uploaded!"
            })
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        return res.status(401).send({
            status: 'error',
            errorCode: 102,
            message: 'Error! ' + err
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `bytea` is typically a better choice than large objects

Comment: and I will probably use that, but I was wondering how to fix this.